# How can I get the frontmost Safari document or tab in JavaScript Automation?

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, javascript-automation

I would like to access the frontmost tab being displayed in Safari and retrieve the URL using the JavaScript Automation scripting in Yosemite Script Editor. I can get the first window, first tab url  using code like:

```
Application('Safari').windows[0].tabs[0].url()
```

I can't figure how to find which window and tab is actually the one being displayed frontmost currently though.

Answer (score 2):

`windows[0]` would normally be frontmost and is the equivalent of doing:

`window 1`

Then use `currentTab`

```
Application('Safari').windows[0].currentTab.url()
```

Comment: That "works" as well as what I posted. I consider this a bug as it only "works" if Safari is visible. If Safari is hidden or in a different Space then it always returns the "oldest" window and not the "front" window. I've submitted a bug report to Apple.